# Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections

Tags: amazon-redshift, sql-workbench-j

I have been using SQL workbench to connect to redshift data.
Suddenly I get this error 'Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections' .
I am not in the initial stages where I am trying to establish a connection. But have been using same credentials/ same host names same laptop etc and have been working fine until yesterday when I encountered this problem.

I have completed system updates, restarted my laptop several times and have started launching a new session but I still keep getting this error message.

Do any of you have a recommendation for me? what do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

check aws security groups. it may be blocking your laptop.

Answer (score 0):

1. Sign-in into AWS Console
2. Search in AWS console for 'Security groups' - You will get 'Security groups (ECS feature)'
3. Select Inbound rules tab < select edit inbound rules (Add Rule: Type=Redshift, Source=MyIP. (auto-fill), Save it.)
4. Also In Redshift- Open your Cluster < Actions < Modify publically accessible setting < Enable < Save Changes

Connect Redshift with SQLWorkbench/J. That's it.